# Problem in using C# generics with method overloading

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to call an overloaded method based on the generic type. I've been doing this in C++ without any pain. But I really don't understand why am not able to do this in C# with generics. Can anybody help me how can I achieve this in C# with generics?

```
class Test<T>
{
    public T Val;

    public void Do(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
        MainClass.Print(Val);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Print(UInt16 val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UInt16: " + val.ToString());
    }

    public static void Print(UInt32 val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UInt32: " + val.ToString());
    }

    public static void Print(UInt64 val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UInt64: " + val.ToString());
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {   
        Test<UInt16> test = new Test<UInt16>();
        test.Do(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: This example won't compile as Do() requires an argument.  In what manner is this not working? Compilation error (other than the above)? Unexpected runtime behavior?

Comment: Forgot to pass the value to Do during my edits, now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work because C# generics are fundamentally different to C++ templates. .NET generic class instantiations are created at run-time, whereas C++ template instantiations are created at compile-time (as far as I know; my C++ is very rusty). The generic `Do<T>` method has to know *at compile time* a single method to call that can be baked into the resulting IL.

The way to accomplish this is to use reflection, or `dynamic` (new in C#4):

```
class Test<T>
{
    public T Val;

    public void Do(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
        dynamic dynVal = Val;
        MainClass.Print(dynVal);
    }
}
```

With `dynamic`, the method lookup will be at runtime. Note that this is completely separate to generics, and will work equally well in non-generic code.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I don't think it'll work.  Dynamic is really of type object in C# and at compile time it won't know which method to call, since there is no method which takes type object.

Comment: Unless I've forgotten my C++, those generics are also compile-time.  At least, I don't recall any mechanism in C++ which would allow a caller to dynamically change the type of the parameters it was passing.

Comment: @Kevin: yes, but the method call is replaced with a dynamic lookup mechanism that ends up calling the correct method. The choice of which method to call is put on hold until runtime.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy: as I've said, my C++ is very rusty.

Comment: A downside to this solution (in the context of the example) is that it will fail at runtime if Test is ever created with a non-integer type. Compile-time errors are generally preferable. The underlying problem with the original code is that there are no guarantees T will always be one of the types which MainClass.Print has an overload for.

Comment: @thecoop I'll be darned, didn't think about trying that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but in your code you have:

```
public void Do(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
        MainClass.Print(Val);
    }

and in you main method you have:

test.Do();  //no parameter provided.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem youre encountering is that C# desn't select the appropriate method based on your type T. You'll have to make a workaound like this:

```
void Print<T>(T val)
{
  switch(val.GetType())
  {
    case typeof(UInt64):
         Console.WriteLine(...); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. In this case I'll forgive you :)